# Angular 2: Is it possible to inject a component to a service?

Tags: angular

Suppose this is my app.module.ts file:

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Comp1,
    Comp2,
    Comp3
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [Service],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Let's also say that the template of AppComponent is:

```
<comp1></comp1>
<comp2></comp2>
```

As you can see I have one main component, AppComponent. It contains two sub-components, Comp1 and Comp2, and I want to inject Comp1 to the Service of the application. How can I do it?

Comment: I assume you want to add Components to page dynamically. Then read http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/ it may help you.

If you want to control Component state from Service, then you should add Observable property to Service. Component that changes state -> listen to that property. Another Service/Component sets value to that property. I.e. Service acts like a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You **`cannot`** do that, I really don't understand why do you want to inject Component in to a Service. It should be the other way.

If you really want to consume the service in Component 1 , you could simply refer the Service and use it inside.

Inside **Component1.ts**

```
import {Service1} from './services/Service1';   

 constructor(private myService: Service1) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sajeetharan said, no you can't do that and I don't think you want to actually inject a component into a service (you can however inject one or many services into another service).

In your example `<comp1>` and `<comp2>` can be used in the app.component view template without injecting comp1 and comp2 into app.component, **just because because components are referenced on a view template, doesn't mean they need to be injected into the component who's view template references them.**

In order to reference components in your app.component view template, angular needs to be able to compile your view templates and resolve all your referenced components.  It does that through traversing the registered modules and looking at the declarations and export collections defined in the modules.

Therefore with your current app.module definition of :

```
...
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Comp1,
    Comp2,
    Comp3
  ],
...
```

the AppComponent view template should be fine to use Comp1,Comp2,and / or Comp3 in it's view template because they are all declared in the same NgModule.  There is no code changed required to the component definitions to facilitate such use.